# If $f$ is log-convex then $f$ is convex

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

Here's my attempt:
$f$ is log-convex. Then:

$\log f(\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y )\leq \lambda \log f(x) + (1-\lambda) \log f(y)$

As $e^x$ is increasing, we can apply it to the inequation without changing its signal. Then:

$f(\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y )\leq f(x)^{\lambda} . f(y)^{(1-\lambda) }$

The left side is alright, but I can't see how to conclude that $f$ is convex.
Can someone help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Apply the [weighted AM-GM inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means#Weighted_AM.E2.80.93GM_inequality) to the right-hand side.

Comment: I believe this statement is false. for example $f(x)=5-e^{-x^2}$ is log-convex but it's not convex.

Comment: But isn't true that $\frac{d²}{dx²} \log (f(x)) \geq 0 $  $ \forall x$ then it is also not log-convex.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmically_convex_function

Answer (score 0):

You can use the fact that the composition $g\circ h$ of an increasing convex function $g$ with a convex function $h$ is still convex.

The composition of the convex increasing function $g( x ) = e^x$ with the convex function $h( x ) = \log f(x)$ must then be convex.

But in this case we have $g\circ h = f$.

Notice that although, as we proved, all $\log$-convex functions are convex, the converse is false. As an exercise, try to come up with an example, it is not difficult.

Comment: Example is $f(x)= x^{2}$

Answer (score 0):

The generalized Arithmetic-Geometric inequality says that
$ax+by \geq x^a y^b$, so you can get $ f(x)^{\lambda}f(y)^{(1-\lambda)} \leq \lambda f(x)+(1-\lambda)f(y) $.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).